# Is Visual Studio 11 beta missing the "Add Deployable Assemblies" menu option?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In **Visual Studio 2010 SP1**, there is an option on the right-click menu on a web project to `Add Deployable Assemblies`. Phil Haack blogged about it [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).

In **Visual Studio 11 beta** and **Visual Studio 2012**, this option appears to be missing. Thankfully, you can easily round trip solutions between VS 2010 and VS 11 so I could just open the solution in VS 2010 to add the MVC assemblies to the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder.

Is it just my installation thats broken or do I need to install anything else to get this working?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `Add Deployable Assemblies` dialog was a feature that enabled you to deploy MVC or Web Pages projects. It was necessary because in older versions all the assemblies were installed into the GAC on your dev machine but you wouldn't necessarily know if that was the case on the server. Thus this tooling gesture that made your project bin-deployable.

Starting with MVC 3 Tools Update we are now using Nuget package references, which means that your project is automatically bin-deployable. Since the tooling gesture is no longer necessary it was removed from VS 11.

Comment: @GeoffAppleford. In VS2012, Do I need to use `CopyLocal` to true since `Add Deployable Assemblies` is not available?

Comment: @Lijo - no the assemblies added via Nuget will automatically be added to the bin folder.

Comment: There's still a problem though if you aren't referencing something via nuget (MVC, for example). How to handle that besides flipping the Copy Local flag to true?

Comment: @ledbutter if you are not using a nuget reference (but instead referencing the binary from the GAC) then setting CopyLocal = true is your only option

Comment: @marcind thanks for the confirmation. Yes, that's what I feared/assumed (I didn't set up this MVC project and am now trying to fix the deployment where the MVC DLL's are missing).

Comment: @ledbutter so have you tried change the binary references to use nugget packages?

Comment: No, we decided to simply install MVC on our web servers, rendering the point moot. I voted for trying nuget but since our infrastructure team was ok with installing MVC, I dropped the issue.