# Add Deployable Assemblies option missing from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I've uploaded an MVC3 website and I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Having seen this before I know that it's an issue where the libraries I need aren't there. I have to bin deploy.

However I can't find the "Add Deployable Assemblies" option when I right click the project.

And according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587355/is-visual-studio-11-beta-missing-the-add-deployable-assemblies-menu-option):

> Starting with MVC 3 Tools Update we are now using Nuget package
>   references, which means that your project is automatically
>   bin-deployable. Since the tooling gesture is no longer necessary it
>   was removed from VS 11.

So why hasn't my application been "automatically bin-deployed" if this is the case?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack1  and you will get the option.

http://iwantmymvc.com/2011-03-23-bin-deploy-aspnet-mvc-3-visual-studio

[image]

[image]

Comment: I still don't see "Add Deployable Dependencies" in VS Ultimate 2012 (Update 3).