# Is there any deployment advice for ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, visual-studio-2012

Phil Haack's seminal post on MVC3 deployment (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) doesn't appear to apply to MVC4 in VS11. There is no Add Deployable Items context menu item in VS11.  Is there anyone deployment advice for MVC4 out of VS11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Add Deployable Items" menu item is really just a convenient way of marking the assemblies as "Copy Local = true".

What I've done prior to VS10 SP1 is this:

1) Create a local /lib/ folder and drop the MVC DLLs in there. (I think Haack's post contains the full list of the ones you need)

2) Mark each as "Copy Local = true" in the Properties window. This tells Visual Studio to always copy the assemblies into the release directory, even if they exist in the GAC

3) Make sure you deploy the DLLs to your web server

Comment: Obviously, this advice isn't MVC 4 specific. Its a little more of a PITA than using a built-in feature, but if VS 11 doesn't make that feature available then this is a good fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "Add Deployable Items" context menu is not necessary in VS11. The project is already bin deployable from the start, and you don't need to do anything to deploy the required dlls. They are automatically included when you publish.

See here for details:

[Is Visual Studio 11 beta missing the "Add Deployable Assemblies" menu option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587355/is-visual-studio-11-beta-missing-the-add-deployable-assemblies-menu-option)

Answer (score -2):

Just install the ASP.NET MVC 4 nuget package. http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer.  As it stands, it is not helpful at all.