# Deploying MVC4: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, dependencies, asp.net-web-api

My very basic .Net 4.5 MVC4 Web Api application runs fine on IIS on my development machine, but when I try to deploy and run on a production machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, I get this message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7 and .Net 4.5 is installed.

I have a ton of NuGet packages installed in the project that came straight from the MVC4 Web Api project template, including Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure. It's not referenced by my project, but seems to be a dependency of a dependency, or something.

I read at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593577/326110 that since it's using NuGet (at least they're talking about MVC3 using NuGet) it should automatically be bin-deployable, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

If I manually copy Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll from my NuGet packages folder to the bin folder on the server, it works, but obviously this doesn't seem like the Right Way to do it :(

Comment: Check out the duplicate link above.  It sounds like the exact same issue.

Comment: That's the same error message, but unfortunately a very different cause and solution :( Thanks for checking.

Comment: Actually, your last sentence makes me think that the dupe actually *is* the same issue and solution: it's not in the GAC, yet something in your code is expecting it to be available.

Comment: It's only in the GAC if you install Visual Studio, which I'd rather avoid on my production web server and build server. The answer I linked to above suggested that, at least since MVC3 Tools Update, having it in the GAC should be no longer required, and it should be bin deployable. The scenario in the question linked by Eric is completely different. He's not even using MVC. Of course the reason why "Could not load file or assembly" messages is always because the runtime can't find the DLL, there are tonnes of different situations and solutions that are covered by that generic message.