# Making an ASP.NET MVC 4 hybrid bin deployable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

This could be me being slightly dim, but I can't figure out how to make my webforms / MVC 4 hybrid application bin deployable (i.e the required assemblies go through to the deployment server if they're not already in the GAC). If it helps understand the process, I made my hybrid loosely based on [Scott Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx).

In VS 2010, there was the Add Deployable Dependencies dialog which I believe did the heavy lifting for you. However, according to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587355/is-visual-studio-11-beta-missing-the-add-deployable-assemblies-menu-option?rq=1) and reinforced by my own experience, this has gone away in 2012. This answer says something about using Nuget to manage the dependencies instead. However, I didn't import my hybrid's assemblies with Nuget. Should I have? Or is there a Nuget package that I need to add retrospectively?

To add a little more context, I've added MVC 4 to the webforms application, done all the changes and all is happy and well on my development machine. I'm then sending it to our build machine using Cruise Control .NET and the build fails, since it doesn't know what MVC and friends are. There is an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that is working fine on the same build machine, so the DLLs must live somewhere. I've tried the MVC 4 application as MVC 3, but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this issue has been fixed. The answer to this problem at least WAS downgrading it to MVC 3, the fact it wasn't working before was a small issue with Visual Source Safe. For others who come across a scenario where they're trying to build an MVC 4 app where they know MVC 3 definitely works, try downgrading.